# Get waterbody info from base map in Leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, polygon, point-in-polygon

I am plotting points on a map using Leaflet, and would like to collect any data I can concerning the water bodies that encompass these points.  I have been making use of polygons from HydroSHEDS (https://hydrosheds.org) to identify waterbody outlines, but this is not a complete list of waterbodies (The default base map used in leaflet seems to have polygon info on many more lakes).

As an example, if I make a map like this:

```
library(leaflet)

Lat<-c(43.847863,43.847199,43.846288,43.852605)
Lon<-c(-74.886135,-74.886111,-74.897731,-74.899169)
LakeID<-c(1,2,3,4)


leaflet() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = Lat, lng = Lon,
                   color = "blue",
                   radius = 2)%>%
  addTiles()
```

For points that fall in a water body, I'd like to get info on the polygon used for that lake, and the name of the lake as well. I can see that the base map has the larger and smaller waterbodies colored blue, and has the name for the larger one "Twitchell Lake", so I assume that data can be queried in some way.

Is there a way I can access this data from the basemap so I could find out:

Polygon used for individual waterbodies
Name of waterbody

Comment: I've suggested this as an enhancement to `osmdata` https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/issues/199

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the credit line at the bottom of the map you'll see that the basemap is data from OpenStreetMap (OSM). There is a network API you can call to query the underlying vector data that is used to draw the map.

The R package `osmar` has some functionality to read OSM data but I can't get it to work at the moment. So I wrote a quick function:

```
getosm <- function(lat, long, tag){
    s = paste0('https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%3Bis_in(',lat,'%2C',long,')-%3E.a%3Bway(pivot.a)%3Bout+tags+bb+geom%3Bout+ids+geom%3Brelation(pivot.a)%5B',tag,'%5D%3Bout+geom%3B')
    rjson::fromJSON(paste(readLines(url(s)),collapse="\n"))
}
```

This function takes a *single* latitude and longitude, together with a tag string you can use to select elements. You probably want to select elements with the  `"natural=water"` tag. So for your first point:

```
w1 = getosm(Lat[1],Lon[1],"natural=water")
```

The returned object is a complex list object. For example the name of the first element (since it can possibly find several features at a location) is:

```
> w1$elements[[1]]$tags$name
[1] "Twitchell Lake"
>
```

The geometry defining the lake is stored in `w1$elements[[1]]$members` object. It has five elements:

```
> length(w1$elements[[1]]$members)
[1] 5
```

which (probably) define the main shoreline and maybe some islands inside the lake. There might be code in `osmar` to construct spatial features from this data, or some other conversion code somewhere.

If there's no water at the queried point then the returned `elements` will be length zero:

```
> w3 = getosm(Lat[3],Lon[3],"natural=water")
> length(w3$elements)
[1] 0
>
```

R could benefit from a package to do queries using this API, especially since `osmar` looks broken. I might investigate the `osmar` problems further.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `osmdata` package. I decided to use `tmap` for plotting just because I'm more familiar with its syntax but there is not real difference between interactive version of `tmap` and `leaflet`.

```r
# packages
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3
library(osmdata)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
library(tmap)

tmap_mode("view")
#> tmap mode set to interactive viewing

# point data
Lat<-c(43.847863, 43.847199, 43.846288, 43.852605)
Lon<-c(-74.886135, -74.886111, -74.897731, -74.899169)
```

I need to define a bounding box to create a query for OSM (read the help page of `?osmdata::opq` and `?osmdata::getbb` for more details) so I manually create a bbox based on those points. You should manually expand that bbox if you want to include more features.

```r
# define a bbox for those points
my_points <- st_sfc(st_multipoint(cbind(Lon, Lat)), crs = 4326)
my_bbox <- st_bbox(my_points)
```

Now I have to create an Overpass Query specifying the appropriate keys and values. I used the same query as @Spacedman but you can read mode details [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features#Water_related) to modify it.

```r
# define tags
my_lakes <- opq(my_bbox) %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "natural", value = "water") %>% 
  osmdata_sf()
```

This is the result. You should read the [vignettes](https://docs.ropensci.org/osmdata/articles/index.html) of `osmdata` package for a more detailed explanation of that output.

```r
my_lakes
#> Object of class 'osmdata' with:
#>                  $bbox : 43.846288,-74.899169,43.852605,-74.886111
#>         $overpass_call : The call submitted to the overpass API
#>                  $meta : metadata including timestamp and version numbers
#>            $osm_points : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 128 points
#>             $osm_lines : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 4 linestrings
#>          $osm_polygons : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 2 polygons
#>        $osm_multilines : NULL
#>     $osm_multipolygons : 'sf' Simple Features Collection with 1 multipolygons
```

Let's check now the polygons and multipolygons objects.

```r
lakes_polygon <- my_lakes$osm_polygons
lakes_polygon
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 3 fields
#> geometry type:  POLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -74.90088 ymin: 43.84064 xmax: -74.87768 ymax: 43.85952
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#>              osm_id        name natural                       geometry
#> 198403657 198403657        <NA>    <NA> POLYGON ((-74.88185 43.8501...
#> 222234302 222234302 Oswego Pond   water POLYGON ((-74.90039 43.853,...

lakes_multipolygon <- my_lakes$osm_multipolygons
lakes_multipolygon
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 4 fields
#> geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -74.90088 ymin: 43.84064 xmax: -74.87768 ymax: 43.85952
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#>          osm_id           name natural         type
#> 4056964 4056964 Twitchell Lake   water multipolygon
#>                               geometry
#> 4056964 MULTIPOLYGON (((-74.88166 4...
```

The polygon object consists of 2 POLYGONS while the multipolygon sf object consists of just 1 MULTIPOLYGON. We can see that both outputs include a variable called `name` that specify the name of the corresponding object according to OpenStreetMap data. Now we can also plot these results. There are a few problems with leaflet and osmdata (i.e [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/631) and [here](https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/issues/188)) but we can easily solve them.

```r
# and plot the result
names(lakes_multipolygon$geometry) <- NULL
names(lakes_multipolygon$geometry[[1]][[1]]) <- NULL

tm_shape(lakes_multipolygon) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "darkred", alpha = 0.5) + 
tm_shape(lakes_polygon) + 
  tm_polygons(col = "darkred") + 
tm_shape(my_points) + 
  tm_dots(col = "darkblue") + 
tm_basemap("OpenStreetMap")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The MULTIPOLYGON object represent the Twitchell lake, the first polygon represent a small island inside the Twitchell Lake while the second polygon represent the other lake.

Comment: I looked at doing a bounding-box query but the questioner asked for polygons containing a point. If you want to do it by bounding box you first have to decide how big a box you need, and that needs adapting since a bounding box query needs to be large enough to catch some of the surrounding polygon, and also do a point-in-polygon test to filter out things that don't have the point in them (using `st_intersects`).

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I didn't understand the OP question.